# Calculate $(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha+\beta})^{(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha-\beta})}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Calculate $(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha+\beta})^{(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha-\beta})}$ where :

$$\alpha=2\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{2\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{2\zeta-\frac{1}{2\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{...}}}}$$
And:
$$\beta=\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{...}}}}$$
(1)_  $$\beta=\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{\beta} \implies \beta=\frac{\beta\zeta(2)+1}{\beta} \implies \beta^2-\beta\zeta(2)-1=0$$
We have $$\Delta=\zeta(2)^2+4\succ0$$
So $$\{_{\beta_{2}=\frac{\zeta(2)+\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2+4}}{2}}^{\beta_{1}=\frac{\zeta(2)-\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2+4}}{2}}$$\  $\beta_{1}\prec0$ so $\beta_{1}$ is rejected And from it we find$$\beta=\frac{\zeta(2)+\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2+4}}{2}$$
(2) _ $$\alpha=2\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{\alpha}\implies \alpha^2-2\zeta(2)\alpha+1$$
\
we have $\Delta=4\zeta(2)^2-4\succ0 $
but $$\{_{\alpha_{2}=\zeta(2)+\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2-1}\succ 0}^{\alpha_{1}=\zeta(2)-\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2-1}\succ 0}$$
So $$(\alpha=\zeta(2)-\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2-1})\vee(\alpha=\zeta(2)+\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2-1})$$
I need to find $$\alpha=?$$ to find $$(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha+\beta})^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha-\beta}}$$

Waiting for your help, thanks

Comment: Well you speak about what ?Function Zeta ? It's unclear . Take the time to edit .

Comment: @user698573 I need to find $\alpha$ to find $(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha+\beta})^{(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha-\beta}})$

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the continued fraction expression $$\alpha = \lim_n \alpha_n$$
where $\alpha_0 = 2\zeta(2)$ and for all $n \ge 1, a_n = 2\zeta(2) - \frac 1{a_{n-1}}$

Experimenting with the first few terms makes it clear that $\alpha \approx 2.95$ which is much greater than $\zeta(2)$, so $$\alpha = \zeta(2)+\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2-1}$$ is correct.

However to prove it, note that $\alpha_0 > 3$ and for any $n\ge 1$, if $\alpha_{n-1} > 2$, then $\frac 1{\alpha_{n-1}} < \frac 12$, and therefore $\alpha_n > 3 - \frac12 > 2$. By induction, for all $n, \alpha_n > 2$, and their limit $\alpha \ge 2$.

Since $\zeta(2)-\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2-1} < 2, \alpha = \zeta(2)+\sqrt{\zeta(2)^2-1}$ (assuming that the sequence converges at all and $\alpha$ is well-defined, but I'm taking that as given).